# How to find out a contact is a whatsapp user or not

Tags: android, android-intent, whatsapp

**I'm trying to find out whether a particular contact is a whatsapp user or not.**

This goes my requirement:

I have a text to share and also have a phone number of a person as well. The priority of my sharing goes as follows

If the phone number is already present in CONTACTS and :

1. if the contact is a whatsapp user, I should call sharing intent of SEND with package set as "com.whatsapp"

i.e:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");           
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
startActivity(intent);
```

2. if the contact not a whatsapp user, I should call intent for default messaging app.

i.e :

```
Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse( "sms:" + phoneNumber ) ); 
intent.putExtra( "sms_body", message ); 
startActivity(intent);
```

If the phone number is not present, create a contact and do as above.

My question now is, how do I find out whether my contact is a whatsapp user or not? Is whatsapp providing any API to find out that?

Thanks in advance

PS: I do not want to show a general sharing intent which shows a list of sharing apps. I may do that only if the device does not have whatsapp application at all.

Comment: did you try to query `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone` ?

Comment: @pskink No. would it have extra info about whatsapp association? Also, in case i'm creating a new contact how would I find out